# Why does Catalina have two HTTP protocol ports specified in Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

While poking around in the Catalina config file on Identity Server, I saw two HTTP portocol ports: 9763, and 9443. Since port 9443 is the default entry point for the Identity Server web interface, what is port 9763 for (backwards compatability?) and is it something I can disable?

Note: 9763 (HTTP) appears to redirect to 9443 (HTTPS) anyway, but when I check this out on a web browser, it doesn't properly redirect to the SSL version as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned already, 9763 is the HTTP port and 9443 is the HTTPS port.

If you go to `http://localhost:9763/carbon`, you should be redirected to `https://localhost:9443/carbon`.

If you want to disable HTTP, you can comment out `Connector` for `9763` in `catalina-server.xml`